# Python prevent decoding HEX to ASCII while removing backslashes from my Var

Tags: python

I want to strip some unwanted symbols from my variable. In this case the symbols are backslashes. I am using a HEX number, and as an example I will show some short simple code down bellow. But I don't want python to convert my HEX to ASCII, how would I prevent this from happening.? I have some long shell codes for asm to work with later which are really long and removing `\` by hand is a long process. I know there are different ways like using `echo -e "x\x\x\x" > output` etc, but my whole script will be written in python. 
Thanks

```
>>> a = "\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"
>>> b = a.strip("\\")
>>> print b
1�Phtv

>>> a = "\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36"
>>> b = a.strip("\\")
>>> print b
123456
```

At the end I would like it to print my var:

```
>>> print b
x31x32x33x34x35x36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no backslashes in your variable:

```py
>>> a = "\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"
>>> print(a)
1ÀPhtv
```

Take newline for example: writing `"\n"` in Python will give you string with one character -- newline -- and no backslashes. See [string literals docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for full syntax of these.

Now, if you really want to write string with such backslashes, you can do it with `r` modifier:

```py
>>> a = r"\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"
>>> print(a)
\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76
>>> print(a.replace('\\', ''))
x31xC0x50x68x74x76
```

But if you want to convert a regular string to hex-coded symbols, you can do it character by character, converting it to number (`"\x31"` == `"1"` --> `49`), then to hex (`"0x31"`), and finally stripping the first character:

```py
>>> a = "\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"
>>> print(''.join([hex(ord(x))[1:] for x in a]))
'x31xc0x50x68x74x76'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your Code.

First the simple one:
`strip()` just removes one occurrence. So you should use `replace("\\", "")`. This will replace every backslash with "", which is the same as removing it.

The second problem is pythons behavior with backslashes:

To get your example working you need to append an 'r' in front of your string to indicate, that it is a raw string. `a = r"\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"`. In raw strings, a backlash doesn't escape a character but just stay a backslash.

```
>>> r"\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x74\x76"
'\\x31\\xC0\\x50\\x68\\x74\\x76'
```

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense completely